# Unable to install libgazebo5 in debian Jessie. Please help

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all, I am not able to install libgazebo5 package in my Debian Jessie system. I read that this package is required for installing gazebo_ros package(ROS jade has a dependency on [this](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/323)).

The package is shown in my synaptic package manager. However, when I try to install it I get the following error.

"libgazebo5:
Package libgazebo5 has no available version, but exists in the database.
This typically means that the package was mentioned in a dependency and never uploaded, has been obsoleted or is not available with the contents of sources.list"

Can someone please help me with this issue. All I can understand from this error is that the package libgazebo5 is not there in the ubuntu vivid distribution(I am using ros packages build for vivid distribution as mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Debian/Installation/Source)).

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222883/unable-to-install-libgazebo5-in-debian-jessie.-please-help/) by [mechatron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25364/mechatron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2015-12-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-12-22**:
Gazebo 5 never hit Jessie: https://packages.qa.debian.org/g/gazebo.html

**Comment by [mechatron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25364/mechatron/) on 2015-12-22**:
Can you please explain what that means ? I was of the impression that I am using libgazebo package built for ubuntu vivid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"There is an effort for migrating ROS packages to Debian which probably can help you to bring gazebo binaries to jessie. https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Robotics/ROS
Check for the http://sir.upc.edu/debian-robotics jessie-robotics mainwhich is managed by Leo Palomo-Avellanade who works in debian-science and uses ROS."

I found answer in another thread in github. I hope this helps others having similar issue.

---

Originally posted by [mechatron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25364/mechatron/) with karma: 56 on 2016-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0